# Unable to load CSS from asset pipeline declaration in /layouts/application in Rails 5, works fine from controller view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm currently working on some basics of rails and I'm having real issues with getting any custom CSS loaded in to my app. At the moment I have a default application CSS file of:

```
...
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

I have just one custom.css.scss file in /assets/stylesheets (I've also tried renaming it to just .css and no joy).

In the application layout I have the following default:
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

I've also tried declaring the CSS directly in  tags in the html.erb and that was fine so it's not something with the CSS code. I also tried pasting the CSS straight in to the application.css file and that didn't work.

EDIT:
I've narrowed down the issue to be realted to the the declaration of 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>` on the /layouts/application.html.erb. The page doesn't pick up the CSS from that code, but if I put that code directly in the controllers view, rather than the layout the CSS works.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: can you show your layout and the generated HTML? are you sure it's rendering the correct layout?

Comment: what if you add this line <%= stylesheet_link_tag "custom", media: "all" %>